# Laravel not running jobs

Tags: php, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I am using **laravel 5.2** and I have my jobs set up as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchTweets::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchTweetMentions::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchTweetListsAddedToo::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\LogRotater::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchReadMes::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchEveMarketPrices::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchEveRegions::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchEveMarketGroupInformation::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchEveMarketTypes::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchEveOnlineRegionTypeHistoryInformation::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\CleanEveTables::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\PublishTweets::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchTwitterBlocks::class,
        \App\Console\Commands\FetchTwitterFollowers::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // ...

        $schedule->command('log_rotater')
            ->everyThirtyMinutes()
            ->withoutOverlapping()
            ->appendOutputTo('storage/logs/log_rotation.log');
    }
}
```

I have commented out the other jobs because I feel if I fix one it will fix them all or I'll have a way to fix them all. Essentially this job never runs.

Ever.

How do I know this? The log files its suppose to rotate grow in size to well over a few gigs when they are never suppose to be bigger then a meg. I use to have this set to daily, but now I changed it to every half hour.

It still doesn't run.

I can run it manually by doing `php artisan log_rotator` and there are no errors, it runs, it rotates the logs life is grand.

But it doesn't seem to want to run when scheduled.

**Ideas?**

### Have you created the actual cronjob to run the scheduler?

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * php ~/personal_site/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

### Does the command even work?

This is an example of one of the outputs:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ php ~/personal_site/artisan schedule:run
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c) >> 'storage/logs/tweets.log' 2>&1 &
```

So .... yes yes it does.

**Help**

### Update two

The following should pretty much tell you anything you need to know.

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ php /home/xxx/personal_site/artisan schedule:run >> /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/cron.log 2>&1
xxx@ubuntu:~$ cd personal_site/storage/
xxx@ubuntu:~/personal_site/storage$ cat cron.log 
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c) >> 'storage/logs/tweets.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_blocks; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_block.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_followers; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775) >> 'storage/logs/twitter_followers.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_mentions; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_mentions.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_lists_added_too; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_list.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c) >> 'storage/logs/tweets.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_blocks; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_block.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_followers; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775) >> 'storage/logs/twitter_followers.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_mentions; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_mentions.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_lists_added_too; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_list.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1357d5ceb1399278a39d91725089a0df39036ecc; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' publish_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1357d5ceb1399278a39d91725089a0df39036ecc) >> 'storage/logs/sent_tweets.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1b9fbd28988b6ce27513da6dcf3d00eec059484c) >> 'storage/logs/tweets.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_blocks; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-8f666afb45a162c3e7fcdd31c3b7334b7321f169) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_block.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_twitter_followers; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-00cca655481aaf25de2c659589a2eb94feaf5775) >> 'storage/logs/twitter_followers.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_mentions; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-ee75cb261c4f273c31e1c7ce526ee8ad0b810907) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_mentions.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' fetch_tweet_lists_added_too; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-3b5a4c06df2d042fff061daba42e20e7e4ff43fc) >> 'storage/logs/tweet_list.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: (touch /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1357d5ceb1399278a39d91725089a0df39036ecc; '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' publish_tweets; rm /home/xxx/personal_site/storage/framework/schedule-1357d5ceb1399278a39d91725089a0df39036ecc) >> 'storage/logs/sent_tweets.log' 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Have you created a cronjob to call `artisan schedule:run`?

Comment: I am 800 percent sure I have but thats a good question so let me check that. @tkausl

Comment: @tkausl I knew I was correct, see the updated post.

Comment: In this case, instead of redirecting stdout and stderr in your cronjob to `/dev/null`, redirect it to some other place and check what gets logged. I am not sure about this, but it _might_ be possible, that `~` is not available from a cronjob.

Comment: What user is your Cron job running? Do it have right file access?

Comment: Also, since your cron job may not run in the same user, "~" doesn't means the same thing as running on your user. Use `/home/username/......`

Comment: @tkausl It runs as current user, which is the user I'm logged in as, and I am trying the logging it out to a .log file to see what happens inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your shedule method I think this is not correct:

```
$schedule->command('log_rotater')
   .....
```

You mention `log_rotater` here; but how does you `$signature` look like in `\App\Console\Commands\LogRotater::class`
It's probably something like `log:rotate`

The argument of the `command()` should be an artisan command; so that defined in `$signature` in `\App\Console\Commands\LogRotater::class`

You mention you're scheduler runs; but it only runs the 'FetchTweets' task; nothing else.

Comment: the signature is: `protected $signature = 'log_rotater';` so it is correct, also Its not that only runs that, it runs all of them, I only showed the fetch tweets task because I didn't want to bombard you all with a bunch of output.

Answer (score 0):

I think @tkausl is on the right track: the "~" at the beginning of your command likely does not point to the root folder you expect...

I'd first remove the stdout/stderr redirection, maybe mail to yourself by adding this at the top of your cron file:

```
MAILTO=me@company.com
MAILFROM=server@company.com
```

That should allow you to see any error message the cron job outputs...

My guess, as I said, is your cron job runs as a different user than you (maybe as root?) and "~/personal_site/artisan" just doesn't exist in this context...

Alternatively, you can also try and use an absolute path straight away and see if that's the issue...

Hope this helps!

Comment: `xxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo crontab -l -u root` gives me:  **no crontab for root** When run as `crontab -l` it shows that I have the job mentioned running under me.